# Explanation of function $|y| = x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

First time posting here.

Studying this book and this statement came across.

> In the equation $|y| = x$, $y$ is not a function of $x$ because every nonnegative $x$-value has two $y$-values. For example, if $x = 3$, $|y| = 3$ has the solutions $y = 3$ and $y = -3$.
>
> Huettenmueller, Rhonda. College algebra demystified. New York: McGraw-Hill Professional, 2014.

So far, I never saw operations on $y$ side of the equation. How can I solve those ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just pretend that $y$ is $x$. Draw your graph the same way, but instead of labeling the vertical axis with "$y$", label it with "$x$", and do similarly for the horizontal axis.

Comment: (Actually, the statement should say every *positive* $x$-value has two $y$-values. For $x=0$, there is only $y=0$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the inverse of $y = |x|$ so you can visualize it by reflecting it over the line $y=x$. If you reason through it, you can observe that $|y| = x$ basically means that $x$ is always positive since the absolute value function will always give you a positive value and that $|y|$ can be any real number. This leads to this plot:

[image]

Observe that it is the inverse of $y = |x|$ and that $y$ has a range of $(-\infty, \infty)$ while the $x$ is always positive. This is not a function since it does not pass the vertical line test.

Comment: I thought absolute value would make y always positive, not x. Am I missing something?

Comment: @F.Zer Realize that in this equation/relation, $x$ depends on $y$, not the other way around. That's because we're *modifying* $y$ (by applying the absolute value) and then equating it to $x$. So, in effect, since $y$ can be anything, but $x$ is always *absolute value* of $y$, $x$ is always positive.

Comment: Thank you. Makes a lot of sense. I never thought _y_ could be dependent variable.  Is there any source where I can see a little more on that matter?

Comment: @F.Zer Remember, $x$ and $y$ are just glorified variable names. By convention we use $y$ to describe output and $x$ as input (so $y$ is dependent in the traditional sense) but here $x$ is dependent on $y$ because $x$ is restricted to positive values because of the absolute value. Just like we always do $y = …$ for our graphs, we can also do $x = …$ to describe something in terms of $y$.

Comment: Great. I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

[image: |y|=x]

The graph of $x=|y|$ doesn't pass the vertical line test.

Answer (score 1):

Let observe that by definition $|y|=x \implies x\ge 0$ and

- $y\ge 0 \implies |y|=x \iff y=x$
- $y< 0 \implies |y|=x \iff -y=x \iff y=-x$

then we have two different function both defined for not negative $x$ values.

[**Plot of |y|=x**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cy%7C%3Dx)

Comment: There's a "\" or 2 "$" too many :)

Comment: @SK19 Thanks! Fixed

Comment: Very interesting. What happens if I choose to plot -2? Is there some absolute value property that prevents from doing that? Maybe I am really a beginner in terms of demonstrations and don’t fully understand it.

Comment: Since $|y|$ is not negative the equation $|y|=-2$ has not solutions

Comment: Thank you. It clarifies that matter.

Answer (score 0):

First solve the equation for y:-
$$|y| = x$$
So 
$$y=\pm x$$
Now let y = f(x)
Therefore, 
$$f(x)=\pm x$$
We know by definition of function that every element of its domain should have only one image but here we can see that $f(x)$ has two values for all $x > 0$, one positive and one negative, so it is not a function.

Comment: The wording of your answer could be improved.  Since $|y| = x$, $x \geq 0$.  For each positive value of $x$, there are two values of $y$, namely $y = \pm x$.

Comment: Sorry for that I am not good at English. You can edit it if you want

Comment: I edited the last sentence.  Please check that it says what you intended.